# What does status_of_proc mean by bracket-points-bracket?

Tags: shell-script, init.d

In an init.d script using a few `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, I got this line to report the status.

```
log_daemon_msg "Status" "$APPNAME" ; status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON && exit 0 || exit $?
```

This works, but it produces (APPNAME='hello') :

```
[ ok ] Status: hello[....] is running.
```

Why do I get `[....]`? What does it mean, if anything? I've been looking into the code of init-functions, but my knowledge of bash scripting is too limited to understand fully what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's from `/lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks`.

```
# Default info blocks put to the left of the screen
log_daemon_msg_pre () {
    if log_use_fancy_output; then
        echo -n "[....] " || true
    fi
}
```

`/lib/lsb/init-functions` is true when the output is going to a terminal that's not pretty much dumb.

I don't know why someone saw it fit to add `[....]` at the beginning of some messages.